# Pip настройка директории для установки пакетов

Tags: python, pip

Pip по умолчанию ставит пакеты в `AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\` что несколько не устраивает.
Хотелось бы вернуть старое поведение когда все пакеты ставились в папку с python, или же указать произвольную папку для установки **по умолчанию**. Устанавливать каждый раз через `-target` неудобно.
Есть возможность это поправить?

Comment: А где сам питон стоит? Сколько питон не ставил (всегда в c:/python) - всегда туда же и пакеты падают.

Comment: c:/python там и установлен, и да раньше все было ок.. а в последних версиях что-то поменялось.

Comment: Ну из идей...может влияет чекбокс "установить питон для всех пользователей", ведь в результате это должно запрещать ему ставить пакеты в папку конкретного пользователя. Ну  и права на запись.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно либо создать конфиг файл для pip, где описать дефолтные значения для ключей командной строки, либо установить специальным образом именованые переменные окружения. Оба способа описаны в юзерзгайде pip https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно ставить зависимости в рантайме, у меня есть [библиотечка](https://github.com/pomponchik/installed) для этого. После окончания работы программы в системе вообще никаких библиотек не остается, то есть становится по сути не важно, куда и как их устанавливать.

Установить библиотеку можно так:

```
pip install instld
```

Это можно сделать один раз и прямо в систему.

Далее использование сводится к применению контекстного менеджера:

```
import installed

with installed('some_package') as context:
  import some_module
```

При входе в контекст, создается временная директория, в которую устанавливаются все пакеты. После выхода из контекста пакеты удаляются, а в программе остается лишь те модули, что вы успели импортировать, пока выполнение происходило внутри контекста. Контексты изолированы друг от друга, их можно вкладывать или запускать один за другим, что позволяет в рамках одного рантайма пользоваться несколькими разными версиями одной библиотеки или даже библиотеками, чьи зависимости несовместимы, и которые иным способом не заставить работать вместе в рамках одной программы.

Учитывайте, что у установки зависимостей в рантайме есть свои минусы. Это создает дополнительную нагрузку на диск и на сеть, а также вносит дополнительные задержки в работу программы. Но в некоторых случаях это имеет смысл. Вот некоторые из них:

- У вас просто нет другого способа запустить конфликтующие зависимости или разные версии одной библиотеки одновременно.
- Вы пишете бенчмарк или тест какой-то библиотеки и вам интересно попробовать несколько версий. Тогда вы можете перебрать их в цикле, открывая на каждой итерации по новому контексту.
- Вы выбираете из нескольких библиотек одного класса и экспериментируете с ними в командной оболочке. В этом случае постоянно выходить из оболочки и выполнять pip install не очень удобно, плюс потом бы пришлось подчищать за собой "мусор" (удалять те пакеты, которые не прошли отбор).
- Вы решили поделиться скриптом с другом и хотите отправить его одним файлом. В этом случае удобнее спрятать установку зависимостей прямо в этот файл.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Дополнил свой ответ.